# X is a compact metric space, which of the following must be true?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $X$ is a compact metric space, $f$ is a continuous function from $X$ $\rightarrow$ $X$, which of the following must be true?
>
> A. $f$ has fixed point
>
> B. $f$ is a closed map
>
> C. $f$  is uniformly continuous

I know C is right by compactness. What about the others?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:**

- For A, consider a two-element set $\{x,y\}$ with the discrete metric.
- For B, use that closed subsets of compact spaces are compact, that compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed, and that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: So B is right？As any closed set in compact metric space is also compact.

Comment: Yes, B is right, though you would probably want to expand a bit on the argument to get full credit for the solution.

Answer (score 6):

For a non-discrete counterexample to A, consider $X=S^1$ and think about rotations. More generally, any nontrivial rotation of $\mathbb R^n$, with $n$ odd, about the origin has only the origin as a fixed point. So take $X=\mathbb D_1 -D_2$ with D_1 a closed disk about the origin and $D_2$ an open disk of smaller radius about the origin.

Comment: but $\mathbb R^n$-$\{0\}$ isn't compact anymore, even if you replace $\mathbb R^n$ by $D^n$.

Comment: @Ittay: I think that in order for rotations of $S^n$ not to have fixed points, you need $n$ to be odd (or, technically, $n=0$ also works, which is really the same thing as my example of a two-point discrete set).

Comment: Thank you both for the remarks, I made some correction.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I like your observation that this is really your example in higher dimensions.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Why n must be odd？